# Deleting elements from dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

Is it exists any simple solution which will allow me solve next problem using LINQ.

e.g. I have **Dictionary<string,int> paths;**

which contains following elements

```
   <"/abc/12", 13>

   <"/test/abc", 22>

   <"/stack/overflow/com", 43>

   <"/stack/exception", 4>
```

and I have a  **List<string> filter** which contains following elements

```
   "/abc"
   "/stack/overflow"
```

And I need to delete those elements from paths dictionary which key doesn't start from the any string provided in filter list. So I should get following results:

```
   <"/abc/12", 13>

   <"/stack/overflow/com", 43>
```

Comment: The answer is likely yes, but I would be better if you show "not-so-simple" solution you already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linq:

```
var toDelete = paths
    .Where(kv => !filter.Any(f => kv.Key.StartsWith(f)));
foreach(var delete in toDelete.Reverse())
    paths.Remove(delete.Key);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/m7tfgq)

Comment: You need a `ToList()` or something like that on the first statement.

Comment: dont forget that LINQ is deferred, so when you remove from paths the foreach will throw an exception because the enumerator will get all confused.

Comment: `toDeletes.Reverse()` solves the issue with modified collection.

Comment: @TimSchmelter This is exactly what I was searching for. Thanks

Comment: You can use the `Where` followed by `ToDictionary` LINQ extension methods to just reassign your `paths` variable: `paths = paths.Where(kv => !filter.Any(f => kv.Key.StartsWith(f))).ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);`.

Comment: @SPFiredrake: noteworthy, however, if the `Dictionary` is large and you want to remove just some key-value-pairs, it is probably more efficient to use `Remove`.

Comment: If the filter is limiting enough, then this method actually becomes faster (because it's the same as materializing using ToList). However, if the filters exclude all but a few elements, then your method is slower. It's a gambit one way or the other. Too many excludes, and the ToDictionary is better. Too few, and the ToList and Remove method is better (even with the Reverse call). There's no one way that will work for all instances.

Comment: @SPFiredrake: The `ToDictionary` has the risk of an `OutOfMemoryException` whereas the `Where`+`foreach` has not ;)

Comment: The only way there's a risk of an `OutOfMemoryException` is if you have millions upon millions of records. Certainly a possibility, but without understanding the context of where this method will be utilized, there's no way to make that judgement call. Your method, while not having a risk of an `OutOfMemoryException`, could still take a CONSIDERABLE amount of time if a vast majority of these millions of records (that would risk the exception with ToDictionary) are excluded, whereas the ToDictionary only has to materialize the few that are remaining. Again, a trade off that should be considered

Comment: @SPFiredrake: But the point is that `ToDictionary` has to materialize an **additional** Dictionary (even if just for a millisecond) that is unnecessary. So if you want to delete 10% of the complete dictionary you have 190% of memory consumption at  this moment. The `OutOfMemoryException` depends not only on the count but also on the size of the strings and - of course - on the available memory.

Comment: @TimSchmelter On the flip side, if you need to delete 90% of the complete dictionary, you will spend a considerable more amount of time, whereas you'd only need to materialize that 10% so a total of 110% memory consumption (of which the old dictionary will eventually get reclaimed anyway since you're reassigning the variable). Like I said, a trade off. Just need to find a happy medium.

Answer (score 0):

for non linq way

create new list toRemove

foreach through paths.keys

inside that loop foreach through filter

if key.contains(filter)    ---- might want to add toupper() or tolower() to both 

then add key to toRemove

then foreach over toRemove
calling paths.remove(toRemoveStr);